# What is the origin of the power icon?

Tags: icons, history, metaphor

What is the origin of the power button? Is it supposed to resemble a physical switch?

Was it originally skeuomorphic UI design?  Did it every move/turn or provide feedback?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn7ZWE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: it looks like you got plenty of toilet paper on the roll - ha

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's a stylised form of the '1' and the '0' for 'On' and 'Off'. You can see the evolution [here](http://designblog.nzeldes.com/2008/05/the-evolution-of-the-onoff-power-switch-symbol/comment-page-2/).

Comment: Ha! I just posted the same thing but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: well, the more you knowI always thought they were meant to look like circuit icons (open / closed)

Comment: Note that according to this [article](http://design.org/blog/meaning-and-design-behind-and) the IEC designates the stylized 0/1 with the 1 half inside the "0" as a  standby button, a full poweroff button has the 1 fully enclosed in the circle.

Comment: The article only claims to be conjecture about the 'evolution' of this symbol, and doesn't offer either references or a 'missing link' symbol which would make the theory plausible. The specific shape of the symbol seems unlikely if it had come from a combination of 0 and 1 - why is the 1 inside the 0? Why is the 0 not closed?

Comment: @jwg It's an IEC standard symbol, the on symbol is IEC-5007 and the off symbol is IEC-5008. Try http://design.org/blog/meaning-and-design-behind-and. Or http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-story-behind-the-design-of-the-power-symbol, or http://gizmodo.com/5612630/the-secret-histories-of-those-ing-computer-symbols.

Comment: I've often wondered if it is 0 & 1 (boolean) or "O" (open) and "|" (Closed) When seen on a rocker switch, I think open or closed circuit.

Comment: @TecBrat given the provenance I would be inclined towards the open/closed circuit

Answer (score 32):

This symbol is comprised of a 1, indicating "on", and a 0, indicating "off".

[image]

It was originally designed to indicate "standby", or a low power state that was neither truly on or off. At that time, a 1 inside of a 0 was the power symbol.

[image]

On December 8, 2004, [IEEE 1621](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1621-2004.html) designated the former standby symbol as the new power symbol and designated a waning moon as the official "standby", or "sleep", symbol.

Comment: Can you identify where (which standard?) the IEEE did the designating?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [IEEE 1621](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1621-2004.html)

Answer (score 9):

While only conjecture and not supported by any evidence, this article makes a pretty good case for the evolution of the standby button: http://designblog.nzeldes.com/2008/05/the-evolution-of-the-onoff-power-switch-symbol/

The short version is that as rocker or toggle switches were replaced by momentary push-button switches the I / O symbols were merged to fit the single button interface.

Comment: Which of the comments are you refering to?

Comment: @Bergi - I wasn't referring to any of the comments. Just the main article - It's the same one that Peter has linked to in his answer.

Comment: Ah, was just wondering, as http://designblog.nzeldes.com/2008/05/the-evolution-of-the-onoff-power-switch-symbol/ would suffice :-)

Comment: It's not the letters I and O but the numbers 1 and 0.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I wasn't suggesting letters or numbers - I just used the characters that were closest to the symbols on the switches that may well mean 1 and 0 but the 1 never looks like a '1'.  I am also not sure what this detail has to do with the validity of my answer.

Comment: @AndrewMartin It's an un-serifed 1. And I wasn't questioning the validity of your answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, so why bring it up? Actually it's a stylised 1 and 0. Very few typefaces have a perfectly circular 0 - something that cannot be replicated on this board. The closest I could get was using a I and O so that's what I used. I also described them as symbols not letters or characters but it looks like you didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

I must say the other answers are pretty convincing and they have a substantial basis in the references cited, but I believe there is another intepretation worth considering. Yet be advised: **this is pure conjecture**.

When you come to think about the word **circuit**, you will realize it resembles the word **circle**, and not only in English. A mechanical power button is, more or less, just a way of closing/opening the circuit. Power supply, capacitors are usually marked with perpendicular lines if I am not mistaken. I always posited that the button simply represents connecting/disconnecting of the circuit.

I write it only as an interesting (I hope) minority report, however, as I cannot provide any evidence that this is how it actually came to be.

Answer (score 0):

The statement I heard within IBM at the time was that this was a visual pun of sorts. Yes, the overlaid 1/0 idea was there, but the primary reference (it was claimed) was to the engineering schematic symbol for a particular kind of valve -- one in which the valve shaft rotates a disk to either block or permit flow through the pipe -- and thus was more directly intended to convey power on/off.

Take this with appropriate dose of skepticism, but i believe I have seen that use of this symbol.

The goal, of course, was to internationalize the machine, back in the days when human factor experts were rediscovering the idea of icons...and others were pointing out that icons weren't universal either, as demonstrated by the general dominance of alphabets over hieroglyphs. Whatever they did was going to generate complaints.

Comment: Maybe we should go with alphabets instead of icons then?